# how to update a number field using another number field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can MongoDB allow updating a number field using another number field in same document ?
Let say I have a document like below :

```
{
   "_id" : "1",
   "a" : 2,
   "b" : 3
}
```

**a** and **b** fields are number fields(decimal,int...)
my goal is update field **b** using field **a**
How can I set **b** like **b = 2*a**.
Is this possible ?

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: My MongoDB version is 3.6.15

Comment: On `3.6` you don't have an option to direct update, You need to first read & then update !! For v`4.2` you can do it in one call !! Anyway `3.6` is so old better upgrade your version asap..

Comment: For  v`>=4.2` you can try this :: `db.getCollection('collectionName').update({},[{$set : {b : { $multiply: [ "$a", 2 ] }}}])` as `.update` will accept aggregation pipeline things can be done in one DB update call..

Comment: thanks, i'll try again with updated version

Comment: @whoami i tried your solution and it works in verison 4.2, thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note :**

1. On v`3.6` you don't have an option for direct update, You need to first read & process in code, then update.
2. For v`>= 4.2` you can do it in one call as [.update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) will accept aggregation pipeline & things can be done in one update call to DB. You can try this :

**Query :**

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').update({}, [{ $set: { b: { $multiply: ["$a", 2] } } }])
```