# MongoDB: Update field using value from another field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Using Mongo shell, I am trying to add a field which has the same value as an existing field for all documents in a collection. Assuming we have two documents :

```
{
   'foo': 'str1'
}
```

and

```
{
   'foo': 'str2'
}
```

I would like to insert a new field `'foo_new'` which has the respective value of `'foo'` as its value, so that the documents become

```
{
   'foo': 'str1'
   'foo_new': 'str1'
}
```

and

```
{
   'foo': 'str2'
   'foo_new': 'str2'
}
```

The command I use to update the collection ('coll' say) in Mongo shell is

```
db.coll.update({}, {$set: {'foo_new': '$foo'}}, {multi: true})
```

The result of running this command are the two updated documents

```
{
   'foo': 'str1'
   'foo_new': '$foo'
}
```

and

```
{
   'foo': 'str2'
   'foo_new': '$foo'
}
```

i.e. `'$foo'` is being interpreted as a literal for some reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to update a number field using another number field in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60418883/how-to-update-a-number-field-using-another-number-field-in-mongodb)

Comment: @whoami: In theory it does. It's exactly what I tried, but my Mongo shell would interpret the "$a"  as the string '$a' not as 2, the value of the field whose key is 'a'.

Comment: S : There is a difference in what you've tried with what has to be done, `.update()` should be in aggregation pipeline :: `[ ]` not as an object !! What is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: @whoami: I also tried putting the update in square brackets. Same issue unfortunately. MongoDB server version: 4.0.16

Comment: Aggregation pipeline in `.updates()` do work only with MongoDB v >=4.2, As stated in answer, With versions below than that you need to first read & then write it back !! Or use an aggregation pipeline to completely create a different collection with required data & dropping existing one..If you're ok with that I can provide a query..

Comment: @whoami: Thanks for pointing out! I'll take the read & write back approach, but thanks for offering to provide a query.

Answer (score 22):

Try this snippet:

```
db.<collection>.update({}, [{$set: {'foo_new': '$foo'}}], {"multi": true})
```

Note the `[]` square brackets in 2nd argument.
More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280419/4050261

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60418883/how-to-update-a-number-field-using-another-number-field-in-mongodb

Comment: If we have create a new document, can we have the new field auto populated with this value. Is there a way to achieve this?  I will basically have a calculation based on 2 other fields. Will the calculation reflect for the new field if we add a new document?

Comment: This isn't a valid solution for Mongo 4.0.

Comment: FWIW I ran into this same issue and didn't need to add the `{"multi": true}` portion, just adding the square brackets around my set criteria did the trick.

Comment: Don't use update() with `{"multi": true}` just use `updateMany()` or `updateOne()`