# How can I add a new field from another one value?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection "people" with documents like this one:

```
{
  _id: "...",
  name: "...",
  age: "..."
}
```

I want to perform an update to all the documents of this collection so they have an extra field "actualName" with the exact same content like "name". I have tried this:

```
db.people.updateMany({}, { $set { actualName: $name } })
```

But I get this error:

> $name is not defined

I'm doing it from MongoSH (Compass).

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60456319/8987128) will help, you can not use the internal field as a value to another field in a simple update query, you can try update with aggregation pipeline. and little similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something with [aggregation updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "actualName": "$name"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gVS364JUP0r)**

Comment: My god... I have tried all the combinations with quotes and aggregation but not this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Mongo 4.2, you can use `aggregation pipeline` with `update()` method to update fields with values of other fields. You can do it like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "actualName": "$name"
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Here is a working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/sqZBDLGJy48