# How can I add each record to the sequence number in mongosh?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I use MongoDB 6.0.

And I'm just trying to update each field with sequence number in mongosh.
I want the field modified and update the collection.

The `sequence_number` will be given from random number.

Here's the example:

```
{
  _id: "1",
  name: "Ken"
},
{
  _id: "2",
  name: "Ryu"
}
```

And what I want to do is this:

```
{
  _id: "1",
  name: "Ken",
  sequence_number: "10"
},
{
  _id: "2",
  name: "Ryu",
  sequence_number: "11"
}
```

Does anyone help me?

Thanks.

I read the question.

[How can I add a new field from another one value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67726809/how-can-i-add-a-new-field-from-another-one-value)

But the approach is a little different.

Comment: Hello, Where does value for `sequence_number` come from? also how do we know which `sequence_number` should be assigned to which document? It'll be better if you include some code that clarifies this.

Comment: `sequence_number` is a random value. It could start 100, 500 or 10. But the each value should be different.

Comment: And the document including `sequence_number` is write back to the same collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all documents in collection and call [`updateOne`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) for each of them.

```js
let sequenceCounter = 10;

db.users.find().forEach((user) => {
    db.users.updateOne(
        { _id: user._id },
        {
            $set: {
                sequence_number: sequenceCounter.toString()
            }
        });
    sequenceCounter++;
});
```

If collection contains large number of documents consider batching the operations with [`bulkWrite()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/).

```js
let sequenceCounter = 10;

const bulkOperations = db.users.find().toArray().map((user)=>{

     return {
        updateOne: {
          filter: { _id: user._id },
          update: { $set: { sequence_number: (sequenceCounter++).toString() } }
        }
      }
      
})

db.users.bulkWrite(bulkOperations);
```

If you are interested in generating the `sequence_numbers` during insertion of documents, consider reading https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment. Mongodb does not have auto increment functionality built in. This approach uses a `counter` collection and js functions that are triggered when creating new documents.